Error 403 when connect Google API for YouTube Content ID
Experience error 403 when connect Google API for video uploading of content ID. PY has used for a long time and it worked properly. I am think IF YouTube has changed Oauth parameter recently. Error dtail as below.
HttpError 403 when requesting
https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtubePartner/v1/rest
returned "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.">
Appreciated if anyone may help me.
Thanks
Applied new client secret json file but still can't resolve the problem.
